# Xcode cloud: unable to open configuration settings file for secrets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

I'm fairly new to Swift development and Xcode. I have Xcode Cloud connected to my GitHub [PRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests) that ensures each commit I push can be archived.

I saw there were a few other similar questions of this error, but they were all [Pods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods) related, and I'm not using Pods.

I've recently moved all my API keys to a Git ignored configuration file. I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/swift-india/secure-secrets-in-ios-app-9f66085800b4). This works locally, but when I push to GitHub, my Xcode Cloud checks fail with:

> Config.xcconfig:1 unable to open configuration settings file

How can I fix this? I noticed that the Xcode Cloud has environment variables, so can I maybe use them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem:

1. Moved the contents of `Config.xcconfig` to `LocalConfig.xcconfig`
2. Changed `Config.xcconfig` to include `LocalConfig.xcconfig` if it's found:

```
#include? "LocalSecrets.xcconfig"
```

3. Added `Config.xcconfig` to source control
4. Ensured `LocalConfig.xcconfig` ignored by source control

More details on the format of xcconfig files:
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev745c5c974